# OpenGL Shadow Glitch

Tags: c++, opengl, c++11, glsl, shadow

### The Problem

I have been trying to implement shadows in OpenGL for some time. I have finally gotten it to a semi-working state in that the shadow appears but covers the scene in strange places [i.e - it is not relative to the light]
[image: The issue at hand]

To further explain the above gif: As I move the light-source further **away** from the scene (to the left) - the shadow stretches further. Why? If anything, it should show more of the scene.

**Update -** I messed around with the lights position and am now being given this result (confusing):
[image]

### Depth Map

Here it is:
[image: The Shadow-map]

### The Code

Because this is a difficult issue to pinpoint - I will post a large chunk of the code I am using in this application.

**The Framebuffer and Depth Texture** - The first thing I needed was a framebuffer to record the depth values of all the drawn objects and then I needed to dump these values into a depth texture (the shadow-map):

```
// Create Framebuffer
FramebufferName = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

// Create and Load Depth Texture
glGenTextures(1, &depthTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

//Attach Texture To Framebuffer
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

//Check for errors
if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    Falcon::Debug::error("ShadowBuffer [Framebuffer] could not be initialized.");
```

**Rendering The Scene** - First I do the shadow-pass which just runs through some basic shaders and outputs to the framebuffer and then I do a second, regular pass that actually draws the scene and does GLSL shadow-map sampling:

```
//Clear
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

//Select Main Shader
normalShader->useShader();

//Bind + Update + Draw
    /* Render Shadows */
    shadowShader->useShader();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, Shadows::framebuffer());
        //Viewport
        glViewport(0,0,640,480);

        //GLM Matrix Definitions
        glm::mat4 shadow_matrix_view;
        glm::mat4 shadow_matrix_projection;

        //View And Projection Calculations
        shadow_matrix_view       =  glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(light.x,light.y,light.z), glm::vec3(0,0,0), glm::vec3(0,1,0));
        shadow_matrix_projection =  glm::perspective(45.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);

        //Calculate MVP(s)
        glm::mat4 shadow_depth_mvp = shadow_matrix_projection * shadow_matrix_view * glm::mat4(1.0);
        glm::mat4 shadow_depth_bias = glm::mat4(0.5,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0.5,0.5,0.5,1) * shadow_depth_mvp;

        //Send Data To The GPU
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shadowShader->getShader(),"depth_matrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, &shadow_depth_mvp[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(normalShader->getShader(),"depth_matrix_bias"), 1, GL_FALSE, &shadow_depth_bias[0][0]);

        renderScene();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    /* Clear */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* Shader */
    normalShader->useShader();

    /* Shadow-map */
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Shadows::shadowmap());
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(normalShader->getShader(),"shadowMap"),0);

    /* Render Scene */
    glViewport(0,0,640,480);
    renderScene();
```

**Fragment Shader** - This is where I calculate the final color to be output and do the depth texture / shadow-map sampling. It could be the source of where I am going wrong:

```
//Shadows
uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap;
in vec4 shadowCoord;

void main()
{
    //Lighting Calculations...
    //Shadow Sampling:
    float visibility = 1.0;
    if (texture(shadowMap, shadowCoord.xyz) < shadowCoord.z){
        visibility = 0.1;
    }

    //Final Output
    outColor = finalColor * visibility;
}
```

---

### Edits

**<1> AMD Hardware Issue** - It was also suggested that this could be an issue of the GPU but I find this hard to believe given that it's a *Radeon HD 6670*. Would it be worth putting in a Nvidia card in to test this theory?

**<2> Suggest Changes** - I made some suggested changes from the comments and answers:

Firstly, I changed the light's perspective projection to an ortho one which gave me the accuracy I needed in the shadow-map so that now I can see the depth clearly (i.e -> it's not all white). In addition, it removes the need for the perspective division so I am using 3-dimensional coordinates for testing this. Below is a screenshot:
[image: New Shadow-map]

Secondly, I changed my texture sampling to this: `visibility = texture(shadowMap,shadowCoord.xyz);` which now always returns 0 and thus I cannot see the scene as it is considered ENTIRELY shadowed.

Thirdly and finally, I made a swap from `GL_LEQUAL` to `GL_LESS` as suggested an no changes occurred.

Comment: 1. I don't see a shadow cast by the small cuboid onto the ground plane - perhaps the camera perspective doesn't let me see it, but still strange that you don't mention it.

Comment: 2. What casts the shadow that wee see?

Comment: 3. Why do you set up such small viewport 640x480 in RTT part, if your target is 1024 pixels squared?

Comment: 4. Does your shadow map look OK?

Comment: 5. how do you compute the value for shadowCoord in your fragment shader?

Comment: 1. That entire black thing eclipsing the scene is currently the only thing I have close to a shadow.

Comment: 2. The small cuboid is suppose to cast the shadow. Done using the sampler comparison in the fragment shader.

Comment: 3. I have just been trying out different Viewport sizes. None work to get the shadow working correctly.

Comment: 4. The shadow-map looks fine (I will update the question)

Comment: 5. The shadowCoord is simply `shadowCoord = depth_bias_matrix * vert.position`

Comment: Are you sure that's your depthmap? Because all the meshes have almost the exact same color. The accuracy may be too low.

Comment: I will try and increase the accuracy and update the question.

Comment: Yeezus - please avoid multiple comments like that.

Answer (score 2):

#### There is something fundamentally wrong with your shader:

```c
uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap; // NOTE: Shadow samplers perform comparison !!

...

if (texture(shadowMap, shadowCoord.xyz) < shadowCoord.z)
```

You have texture compare vs. reference enabled. That means that the 3<sup>rd</sup> texture coordinate is going to be compared by the `texture (...)` function and the returned value is going to be the result of the test function (`GL_LEQUAL` in this case).

In other words, `texture (...)` will return either **0.0** (fail) or **1.0** (pass) by comparing the looked up depth at `shadowCoord.xy` to the value of `shadowCoord.z`. You are doing this test twice.

#### Consider using this altered code instead:

```c
float visibility = texture(shadowMap, shadowCoord.xyz);
```

That is not going to produce quite the results you want because your comparison function is `GL_LEQUAL`, but it is a start. Consider changing the comparison function to `GL_LESS` to get an exact functional match.

Comment: After modifying the shader to support the fail or pass sampling - I got the same result shown in the question on the second image.

Comment: Can you update your question to show what you tried? This is certainly a problem, though I did not think it was your only problem, it would have been too complicated to explain in a comment. One other thing that immediately comes to mind is that for some reason you are using 4 dimensional texture coordinates yet I see no homogeneous divide.